# Return NA or NULL for nonexistant columns in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I am looking for an elegant way to return the value of a column if it exists and (a vector of) `NA` or `NULL` if it doesn't. Addressing it directly yields an `undefined columns` error, and using subsetting yields a 0-column data frame. Is there an elegant built-in way, short of defining a function to do this?

```
> example(data.frame)
# output omitted
> head(d, 1)
  x y fac
1 1 1   A
> head(d['x'], 1)
  x
1 1

# Works when accessing column using $
> head(d$z, 1)
NULL
# Not satisfactory
> head(d['z'], 1)
Error in `[.data.frame`(d, "z") : undefined columns selected
> head(d[colnames(d) == 'z'], 1)
data frame with 0 columns and 1 rows
```

**EDIT**: Of course this one-liner does the job. I'm looking for more R-ish ways.

```
> safe.index <- function(df, n)
     if (any(n %in% colnames(df))) df[n] else rep(NA, nrow(df))
> head(safe.index(d, 'z'), 1)
[1] NA
```

Comment: Seems like a reasonably "R-ish" way to me :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: Any one-liner that replicates existing (?) functionality is one one-liner too much, in my opinion. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: The requirements for the error handling appear to be quite specific (return an `NA` vector when `n` is not in `names(d)`), so I agree with @CarlWitthoft that you might be best off writing a custom solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to go about this is to test for the presence of, in this case, `'z'` in the column names of `d` before trying to subset:

```
if('z' %in% names(d)){
  head(d['z'],1)
} else {
  NA
}
```

Another way would be with `tryCatch` and condition handling:

```
# Actually, the following line defining e isn't really necessary.
# e <- simpleError("stopped")
safe.index <- function(df, n){
  tryCatch(df[n], error = function(e)return(rep(NA, nrow(df))))
}
head(safe.index(d, 'z'), 1)
# [1] NA

head(safe.index(d, 'x'), 1)
#   x
# 1 1
```

One potential drawback is that the above solution using `tryCatch` would return an `NA` vector no matter what the error, not only in the case that `n` is not a column name.

Comment: @user946850, despite my comment above, I've updated the answer here to better match your specifications and took out an unnecessary piece of code.

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
data <- data.frame(x = 1:2, y = 2:3, z = 3:4)
outCol <- function(df, name){
  unlist(ifelse(name %in% names(df),df[name],list(rep(NA,nrow(df)))))
}
outCol(data, 'x')
[1] 1 2
outCol(data, 'u')
[1] NA NA
```